# Design of Experiments on Minitab output

Tags: experiment-design, minitab

I am trying to create a factorial design using Minitab.  I have 2^4=16 runs, I would like to divide these up into 4 blocks, to spread the experiment across 4 days. I will have 4 judges to complete each of the blocks.

Day one: Judge 1; block 1.   Judge 2; block 2.....

Day two: Judge 2; block 1, judge 3 block 2.

At the end of the four days each judge will have completed each block, but in different orders.

I'm stuck here because my output seems to make the 4 blocks, but how do I know from here what each judge is to do each day? Its not outlines the way I was hoping it would be.  Any assistance?

[image]